Pass Android project from new Android studio version
I made some Android project using Android Studio Bumblebee, now I changed my pc with the newest and I installed the last version of Android Studio Koala. So if I try to open the project I can see the following error message:
Unsupported Gradle JVM.

Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.11 and Gradle 5.4.1.

Possible solutions:
 - Upgrade to Gradle 8.5 and re-sync
 - Upgrade to Gradle 7.2 and re-sync


update your gradle version

The error indicates a mismatch between your project's Gradle configuration and the Java version. Upgrading Java to a supported version might resolve the issue.
In your case Gradle 5.4.1 support java version 11 (LTS).
If you want to use Java 17, you need to upgrade Gradle to 7.2(or 8.5) version.
